# Close certain notifications using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, notifications

This is the script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "NotificationCenter"
        set numwins to (count windows)
        repeat with i from numwins to 1 by -1
            tell window i
                set temp to value of static text 1
            end tell
            if temp contains "Disk Not Ejected Properly" then
                click button "Close" of window i
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get static text 1 of window 1 of process \"NotificationCenter\". Invalid index." number -1719 from static text 1 of window 1 of process "NotificationCenter"
```

I'm running MacOS Big Sur 11.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can’t get static text 1 of window 1

The Notification Center window does not contain a static text as an immediate child. You need to navigate the hierarchy down to the texts within a notification.

```
get static text 1 of group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window i
```

> Can’t get button "Close"

You also can't click a button that doesn't exist. Perform the close action on the notifications instead, which you can get using `actions … where description is "Close"`.

```
perform (first action of group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window i where description is "Close")
```

Comment: did OP ever get this working? using the text inc comments of this question, I cannot get it to work. it would be great to post the working solution in the answer.

Comment: @majorgear The comments don't add anything that isn't given in the answer itself. What do you mean by "cannot get it to work", what error do you get? What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: Works on Montery 12.6. With Ventura 13.0.1 , gets message - error "System Events got an error: Can’t get scroll area 1 of window 1 of process \"Notification Center\". Invalid index." number -1719 from scroll area 1 of window 1 of process "Notification Center"
"

Comment: Got it working on Ventura ```tell application "System Events"
 try
  set _groups to groups of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Notification Center" of application process "NotificationCenter"
  
  repeat with _group in _groups
   set temp to value of static text 1 of _group
   if temp contains "Disk Not Ejected Properly" then
    perform (first action of _group where description is "Close")
   end if
  
  end repeat
  
 end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 4):

From the comment by [@majorgear](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423133/close-certain-notifications-using-applescript?newreg=7c03f4c8094d4265997eb0d399e551e5#comment652718_423134), I was able to make it work with a bunch of "Background Items Added" notifications that appeared after upgrading to Mac OS Ventura:

```
tell application "System Events"
   try
     set _groups to groups of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Notification Center" of application process "NotificationCenter"
    repeat with _group in _groups
      set temp to value of static text 1 of _group
      if temp contains "Background Items Added" then
        perform (first action of _group where description is "Close")
       end if
    end repeat
  end try 
end tell
```